# Joining three csv files with different header in NiFi

Tags: etl, apache-nifi

I am new to nifi. Currently I have a use case where I have to merge three csv files that I extracted from the XLXS files. I need to merge them on the basis of **NPI** column in all the three csv file.

files1.xlsx looks like-

```
NPI FULL_NAME   LAST_NAME   FIRST_NAME
1003002627  Arora Himanshu  Arora   Himanshu
1003007204  Arora Vishal  Arora Vishal
```

files2.xlsx looks like-

```
NPI No  Employee Number CHI/SL Acct-Unit
1003002627  147536  5812207
1003007204  185793  5854207
```

files3.xlsx looks like -

```
Individual NPI  Group NPI   Market
1003002627  1396935714  Houston
1003007204  1396935714  Houston
```

I want to left join on my first csv with the specific column in the other csv file so that my desired output is

```
NPI Full Name Employee Number Market
1003002627  Arora Himanshu 147536 Houston
1003007204  Arora Vishal 185793 Houston
```

I tried with the Query Record processor but I don't know how three different schema from three different csv file should I combine together. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

This is what I have tried.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

NiFi doesn't have the ability to do what amounts to a SQL join on three different record sets like this out of the box, but there is a work around here if you know Python:

1. Zip them up.
2. Ingest the zip file.
3. Use `PutFile` to put the zip to a standard location.
4. Write a Python script that will unzip the zip for you and do the merging.
5. Call the Python script immediately after `PutFile` with the `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor.

The `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor will read `stdout`, so just write your combined output with `sys.stdout` and it'll get back into NiFi.